# python selenium WebDriverWait doesn't find element on the page although it's present

Tags: python, selenium, search, wait

I'm trying to search for an auction on the page and wait until the searched auction title is present in first element on the list. To do this I'm using

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(expected_conditions.text_to_be_present_in_element(view_consignments_page._first_result, view_consignments_page._title_uuid))
```

Sometimes it's working, and sometimes it's not - although the text is present in first element on the list. In this case test failed:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEnZn.png

In the bottom left corner there's a field "Szukaj" (Search) to which I post auction title, click search and scroll the page to the top, to make sure element is visible. Search finds the element and it's present as first result, but WebDriverWait doesn't catch it.

Do you know why sometimes it works and sometimes doesn't?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the wait time?

Comment: it's not the case because i'm making screenshot at the end of every failed test and it shows that the search function has finished and the result is proper, as you can see on my imgur screenshot